# Pushsharp - APNS service chewing up memory and dying after ~12 hours

Tags: c#, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

So I have a windows service that sends APNS push notifications. It works by creating a PushBroker and queuing notifications (never stops it) constantly (~20000/min). I'm using the latest stable release from the nuget public feed.

Anyways after ~12 hours the notifications slow to a trickle and I notice the service is consuming ~12Gb of RAM. I suspected it the internal notifaction queue  growing over time but looking through the source code but can't find anywhere it could grow uncontrollably. 
Is this a known issue?

Comment: Code would be helpful. It's probably a bug in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I pulled the latest from PushSharp master branch and it worked. Note that the latest beta on Nuget (2.1.2) has a few issues.